# Consider the stochastic process $\{X_t\}$ given by $X_t=\cos(2\pi ft+\alpha\beta)$

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Consider the stochastic process $\{X_t\}$ given by $X_t=\cos(2\pi ft+\alpha\beta)$, where $f,t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \sim Bernoulli(p)$ and $\beta \sim U\left(-\pi/2, \pi/2 \right)$. Find the mean function $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$.

My attempt: Basically, $\mu_X (t) = \mathbb{E}[X_t] = \mathbb{E}\left[\cos(2\pi ft+\alpha\beta)\right]$. In this case, the calculation of the expected value is by definition, but how do I set up the integral? Since I have the r.v. $\alpha, \beta$ affected by the cosine? I was thinking maybe of using the joint distribution, but under the assumption of independence. How would you do it, please?

Comment: $$
    \mathbb{E}[\cos(2\pi ft + \alpha \beta)] = \mathbb{P}(\alpha = 1)\mathbb{E}[\cos(2\pi ft + \beta)] + \mathbb{P}(\alpha = 0)\cos(2\pi ft)
$$

Comment: You cannot find it without further information.

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn OP is explicitly saying that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not given to be independent.